# How to Hide "Sign In With Google" button FirebaseUI

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin, firebaseui

i am trying to use FirebaseUI to singIn the user
My aim is to signIn the user with `Sign In with Email` only not `Sign In With Google`
i am using

```
 var authUI: FUIAuth = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()!
let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [FUIGoogleAuth()]
```

The problem is it providing two buttons `Sing in With Google` and `Sign in with Email` but i only need `Sign in With Email`

```
authUI.isSignInWithEmailHidden = false
```

is available but not the `isSignInWithGoogleHidden`
is there any way

Comment: If you don't need any additional providers, don't include code for other providers. You don't need `let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [FUIGoogleAuth()]` unless you're using Google auth.

Comment: i want to customisation of login screen that  "FUIGoogleAuth()" provide